# psql: could not connect to server [ubuntu]

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Under the postgres user, I tried the `psql` command and I'm getting this error:

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>       Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

But when I run `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql`, it is working.

Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: What does `which psql` show you?

Comment: @Milen, do you mean what is shown when I type the command **psql**?
I already mentioned it above.

Answer (score 4):

the above issue seems related to PostgreSQL default port no,

Change the port no in postgresql.conf file and restart the DB server. if u have changed the port while installing.

(OR)

instead of psql type full command like

```
 "psql -p 5432 -h localhost"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could include the database user too:

`psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Did you reinstall the postgresql-9.6.3 ?

You need to uninstall postgresql completely

`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove postgresql*`

`sudo apt install postgresql-9.6`